# CKEditor4, change autocomplete dataSource

Tags: angular, ckeditor4.x

I have a custom build used in my project (Angular 11), and a wrapper over the ckeditor to make it easier to send data to ckeditor instance (singleton).
I created a custom plugin 'autotag' which enables the autocomplete. This is added once, so on the second ckeditor initialization, the autocomplete dataSource will be the same as the first ckeditor.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'autotag', {
      requires: 'autocomplete,textmatch',
    
      init: function( editor ) {
        editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
          var config: any = {};
    
          // Called when the user types in the editor or moves the caret.
          // The range represents the caret position.
          function textTestCallback( range ) {
            // You do not want to autocomplete a non-empty selection.
            if ( !range.collapsed ) {
              return null;
            }
    
            // Use the text match plugin which does the tricky job of performing
            // a text search in the DOM. The "matchCallback" function should return
            // a matching fragment of the text.
            return CKEDITOR.plugins.textMatch.match( range, matchCallback );
          }
    
          // Returns the position of the matching text.
          // It matches a word starting from the '#' character
          // up to the caret position.
          function matchCallback( text, offset ) {
            // Get the text before the caret.
            var left = text.slice( 0, offset ),
              // Will look for '${' followed by anything.
              match = left.match(autocompleteConfig.regexp);
            
            if ( !match ) {
              return null;
            }
            return {
              start: match.index,
              end: offset
            };
          }
    
          config.textTestCallback = textTestCallback;
    
          // The itemsArray variable is the example "database".
          var itemsArray = autocompleteConfig.items;

          // Returns (through its callback) the suggestions for the current query.
          function dataCallback( matchInfo, callback ) {
            // Remove the '${' tag.
            var query = matchInfo.query.substring( 2 );
    
            // Simple search.
            // Filter the entire items array so only the items that start
            // with the query remain.

            var suggestions = itemsArray.filter( function( item ) {
              return String( item.name ).indexOf( query ) == 0;
            } );
    
            // Note: The callback function can also be executed asynchronously
            // so dataCallback can do an XHR request or use any other asynchronous API.
            callback( suggestions );
          }
    
          config.dataCallback = dataCallback;
    
          // Define the templates of the autocomplete suggestions dropdown and output text.
          config.itemTemplate = autocompleteConfig.itemTemplate;
          config.outputTemplate = autocompleteConfig.outputTemplate;
    
          // Attach autocomplete to the editor.
          new CKEDITOR.plugins.autocomplete( editor, config );
        } );
      }
```

Is there a way to resend the dataCallback function to the autocomplete plugin?

I tried to re-add the 'autotag' custom plugin, but it did not work, because it was already registered.